# Multiple versions of the same Python installed

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python, symlink

I installed Python3 via `brew`:

```
brew install python@3.9
```

And following the symlink chain of `which python3` leads to:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  41 27 Jul 17:44 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/bin/python3

$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python\@3.9/3.9.13_1/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  55 23 Jul 08:45 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/bin/python3 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python\@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  9 23 Jul 08:44 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -> python3.9

$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python\@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  13620 23 Jul 08:42 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
```

I also installed `offlineimap` with:

```
python3 -m pip install offlineimap
```

And the shebang line shows:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
```

which points to a different binary:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  57 23 Jul 08:45 /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9

$ ls -l /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  13620 23 Jul 08:42 /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
```

and the two have the same versions:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.13
$ /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.13
```

How could I have installed two instances of the same Python? How can I uninstall the non-brew version?

Comment: For me, `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9` is a symlink pointing to `../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1`. Are you sure that in your case it's pointing to a different binary?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Indeed, for me too. So it seems that both point to the same binary, and I was led astray because the binary inside `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9` is following the symlink of `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/` two nodes above, right? Can you write an answer?

Comment: I hope any answer will clear the confusion between python3 (and pip3) installed in /usr/local/bin and python3 (and pip3) installed in /usr/bin.

Comment: @Gilby that is a separate question and I think answered here before. This question is about various links and files made by homebrew

Comment: @mmmmmm Can you link that answer here?

Comment: I could not find an exact answer but it is implicit in many of them asking how to upgrade python - if you really want to know ask and either someone else will know the duplicate or in a day or two I could attempt a fuller answer but I would have missed the details in this question so would not be complete.

Comment: @mmmmmm I don't have `/usr/bin/python3` on my system. I have `/usr/bin/python`, which is Python2 from Apple that ships with the system, so maybe that is the answer.

Comment: @miguelmorin That is noting to do with your question. Your question is about how Homebrew installs python. Nothing you mentioned in it touches anything in /usr/bin All the files you mention are from Homebrew

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, absolutely, I asked it out of curiosity. I can deleted all these comments relating to `/usr/bin/` if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, and maybe in general, `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9` is a symlink pointing to `../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1`, and both correspond to Homebrew's Python 3: no duplicate executable. In contrast, `/usr/bin/python3` is provided by Apple. On my machine, it's version 3.8.9 of Python, in contrast to Homebrew's version 3.9.13.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew installs the Apple Silicon binaries in `/opt/homebrew` and the Intel ones in `/usr/local` in addition to making a symbolic link for the actual program Which is outside your path to a location in the expected path. You should have two copies of python and maybe three if you have that Apple Silicon history.

- https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Once nice thing on homebrew, is you can usually check the installed formulas and [do a clean removal](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ), then just reinstall the versions you need.

Is there a problem with letting the path manage which of the programs gets called?

Comment: The question was about `/usr/local/opt`, not `/opt`, and at least on my (Intel) machine, those are different: `/opt` came from MacPorts, `/usr/local` and `/usr/local/opt` from Homebrew.

Comment: Hmm - I have revised this for the three locations.  Thanks for pointing out my error @JohnPalmieri